# What is the point in using fork() system call when both the processes (parent and child) work on the same code?

Tags: c, fork

I read that the parent and the child will work on the identical code after the `fork()` system call. I cannot understand the point of doing a `fork()` as I cannot understand what good will it do in executing the same code twice.

Comment: Simply do something else in the child/parent process? `pid_t pid = fork(); if (pid == 0){ ... } else { ... }`. (Don't forget to check for `-1` too)

Comment: It only executes the same code twice if you tell it to.

Comment: It can execute the same code with different data and a different stack.

Comment: Doesn't make any advantage in a multiprocessing system?

Comment: "*I cannot understand what good will it do in executing the same code twice*" if we wouldn't had the need to do so machines, computers, robots wouldn't exist, would they? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `fork()` is different in the child and parent processes, so you'll typically have something along the lines of

```
pid_t child_pid = fork()
if (child_pid == 0) {
  // do stuff in child process
} else {
  // do stuff in parent process
}
```

Comment: Remark: Don't forget to check whether the returned value is `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if else condition to execute different piece of code for parent and child. As fork returns 0 to the child process and it returns pid of the child to the parent. Use this as the differentator in the if condition.